# Se me repite la función AJAX varias veces

Tags: javascript

Compañeros, en esta ocación tengo una duda respecto al funcionamiento de AJAX y JQuery.

La primera página (pedir_fichas.php) tiene un código AJAX que me permite enviar datos de varios checkboxes:

```
$(document).on("click", "#pedido", function(){
        var pedido=$("#formulario").serialize();
        $.ajax({  
            type:"POST",
            url:"pedido.php",
            data:pedido,
            success:function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Los datos se tomas gracias a un funcionario y se envían a pedido.php:

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
$cc=$_POST['cedula'];
if ($_REQUEST['productos']!=""){
    $fecha=date("o-m-d", time());
    if (is_array($_REQUEST['productos'])) {
         while (list($key, $value)=each($_REQUEST['productos'])) {
             $pedido=mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO pedidos (fecha_pedido, estado_pedido, doc_in, cod_prod) VALUES ('$fecha', 'Sin observar.','$cc', '$value')");
             if (!$pedido) {
                 echo "Error al realizar el pedido.";
             }else{
                 echo "El pedido se realizó con éxito el pedido.";
             }
         }
     }
 }
 ?>
```

Los datos llegan perfectamente y se suben a la base datos. El problema es ese, que **no se sube un sólo registro, si no que se me duplica varias veces**; además de esto, al enviarse los datos pedir_fichas.php se refresca completamente, en vez de quedarse sin modificación. Cuando pedir_fichas es llamdado (mediante AJAX) a inicio.php, al dar click en el botón pedir (para que se envíen los datos, me muestra la página principal, la página de inicio (pero los datos s eme envían correctamente. Quisiera saber cómo evitar eso o resolverlo.

PD: No siempre ocurre, es en ocaciones que este "loop" se muestra, pero siempre me devuelve y se refresca la página.

Comment: Hay algo mas que no vemos en el código y debe ser lo que ocasiona el problema. Probablemente sea otro código que trata de hacer lo mismo. En cuanto a la redirección, es posible que el botón tenga algún enlace hacia algún lugar.

Comment: creo que el problema es tu while, ya que si es true va a seguir haciendo el insert..

Comment: Efectivamente, el formulario está dentro de un while, para que me pueda enviar todos los datos (traídos de una base de datos). Respecto al while de pedido.php, ¿Cómo lo podría mejorar?

Comment: Esto es todo lo que dice el botón. echo "<button id='pedido'>Pedir</button>";

Comment: también seria bueno que le agregaras al evento `onclick` un evento `unbind` antes

Comment: La verdad, por el momento sólo me interesa que se me suba 1 sólo dato y no me los repita.